# Preventing inbreeding in Muscovy duck flock

Tags: breeding, ducks

I have 4 adult muscovy ducks. A drake and hen each of blue and black. I have no idea of their lineage, so they may or may not be related, as they all came from the same flock. The black hen has a dozen 5 week old ducklings, and the blue hen is sitting on approximately another dozen eggs, due to hatch in the next couple weeks.

What steps should I take to avoid issues like birth defects due to inbreeding? Is it necessary to get rid of all the drakes (including babies), and introduce new drakes to prevent problems?